# Spark String column to element array with a case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a following string in spark dataframe column.

```
X1|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A1|B1|C1|D1|O1|P1|Q1|R1|S1|X2|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A2|B2|C2|D2|O2|P2|Q2|R2|S2|X3|[MODULE3|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A3|B3|C3|D3|O3|P3|Q3|R3|S3
```

This is actually device data of three separate  devices X1, X2,X3 (number of devices could be vary)

```
X1|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A1|B1|C1|D1|O1|P1|Q1|R1|S1|
X2|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A2|B2|C2|D2|O2|P2|Q2|R2|S2|
X3|[MODULE3|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A3|B3|C3|D3|O3|P3|Q3|R3|S3|
```

Here a device is represented with case class Device :

```
case class Device(deviceId:String, status:String, a:String, b:String, c:String, ........,s: String)
```

with mapping analogous to following.

```
X1 - deviceId
[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME] - status
A1 - a
.....
```

I have written a function `split_device_column` to split the string to Seq[String] of size 33 in this case (Size would be always multiplier of 11 depending on number of devices).

```
def split_device_column (s: String): Seq[String] = {...}

 X1
 [MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]
 A1
 B1
 C1
 D1
 O1
 P1
 Q1
 R1
 S1
 X2
 [MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]
 A2
 B2
 C2
 D2
 O2
 P2
 Q2
 R2
 S2
 X3
 [MODULE3|SYNC|DATE:TIME]
 ...
 ...
 S3
```

I could not figure out a way to convert this sequence to case class element array. I do understand this has to go inside a udf most likely.

Any inputs on this ?

Comment: Is this a terrible question to get down voted ?

Comment: you want to separate the string into separate columns or cast to the case class?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan it's to seperate columns.

Comment: you have only one row in the input dataframe ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan This is column is a part of large dataframe.

Comment: I was asking abouut row

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have millions of rows in the input dataframe

Comment: so each row has data like `X1|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A1|B1|C1|D1|O1|P1|Q1|R1|S1|X2|[MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A2|B2|C2|D2|O2|P2|Q2|R2|S2|X3|[MODULE3|SYNC|DATE:TIME]|A3|B3|C3|D3|O3|P3|Q3|R3|S3` ?

Comment: yes, size could be vary, at times there could be no data at all. For example it could be go to more than X1000. Since there are more modules the update field could also be repeated. [MODULE1|SYNC|DATE:TIME];[MODULE2|UPDATED|DATE:TIME];[MODULE3|SYNC|DATE:TIME] likewise(if that matters)